# Error connecting to the Mongo database. bad auth Authentication failed heroku + atlas mongodb + strapi

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, strapi, mongodb-atlas

I might not have enough code here to provide.

I am currently using strapi and running my app on heroku + atlas mongodb.  Everything was working fine when I was running the app with postgresql by heroku but I am migrating everything to atlas mongodb instead.

in strapi I have my config as

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "strapi-hook-mongoose",
      "settings": {
        "client": "mongo",
        "host": "${process.env.DATABASE_HOST}",
        "port": "${process.env.DATABASE_PORT}",
        "database": "${process.env.DATABASE_NAME}",
        "username": "${process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME}",
        "password": "${process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
      },
      "options": {
        "useNullAsDefault": true,
        "ssl": "${process.env.DATABASE_SSL}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

these configs are in `.env` which if running locally the file would look like

```
DATABASE_HOST=xxxxxxx-shard-00-00-xxxxxx.mongodb.net:25758,xxxxxxx-shard-00-01-xxxxxx.mongodb.net:25758,xxxxxxx-shard-00-02-xxxxxx.mongodb.net:25758/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=xxxxxxx-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true
DATABASE_PORT=25758
DATABASE_USERNAME=xxxxx
DATABASE_PASSWORD=xxxxx
DATABASE_NAME=xxxxx
DATABASE_SSL=true
```

if I run it locally, it works perfectly and able to connect to DB.

so I deployed to heroku and went to heroku's setting to config vars.  I configured the same vars as what I have in the `.env` file

I also checked atlas mongodb's ip whitelist, I whitelist to all traffics (any ip) so this shouldn't be the problem.

But as mentioned, I used the same `.env` locally and `config vars` on heroku....but on heroku I got this error message

`error Error connecting to the Mongo database. bad auth Authentication failed.`

Anyone has suggestions on the reason authentication would fail?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

`DATABASE_SSL=true` Environment Variables don't support boolean values, meaning it's passing that as a string. For now you will need to manually set that value in your config and not pass it over env in heroku.